# How can we render HTML and CSS from TS file in Angular? Where Code for HTML and CSS will get from the API Response

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

The Scenario is I am having my component Template code for HTML and CSS in Database which I will get on call of API (response). When I will get code from API response I just want to render that on my template preview but there is one more challenge that after rendering it data bindings should work like conditional directives ( *ngIf or *ngFor ) need to work properly (code in response came with conditions and variable names). I just want to render and bind data in .ts file and change data on Runtime by passing data in form and reflect in the template preview.

Comment: Please include in your question the code that you have tried and your one challenge with that so that we may best assist you here.

Comment: Does this documentation answer you question: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader ?